# Malicious activity on website using site's search bar

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, security

It started with a few but now the number has increased to more than a hundred. I am seeing strange urls getting hit as errors in my Google search console, not sure how is this being done but someone is using the search bar, and it's algo as their tool.
[image]

```
https://www.example.com/?search=L%C3%A0m%20th%E1%BA%BF%20n%C3%A0o%20%C4%91%E1%BB%83%20ch%E1%BB%8Dn%20c%C3%A1c%20tr%C3%B2%20ch%C6%A1i%20b%C3%B3ng%20%C4%91%C3%A1%20c%E1%BB%A7a%20x%E1%BB%95%20s%E1%BB%91%E3%80%90Sao%20ch%C3%A9p%20link%E2%88%B6879783.com%E3%80%91Ho%C3%A0n%20tr%E1%BA%A3%20m%E1%BB%97i%20ng%C3%A0y,%20nh%E1%BA%ADn%20g%C3%B3i%20qu%C3%A0%20cho%20l%E1%BA%A7n%20g%E1%BB%ADi%20ti%E1%BB%81n%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A7u%20ti%C3%AAn%E3%80%91Ph%C3%A2n%20t%C3%ADch%20c%C3%A1%20c%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c%20th%E1%BB%83%20thao%20b%C3%B3ng%20%C4%91%C3%A1%20ng%C3%A0y%206%20th%C3%A1ng%205%E3%80%90M%E1%BB%9F%20Link%E2%88%B6879783.com%E3%80%91N%E1%BB%81n%20t%E1%BA%A3ng%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A3m%20b%E1%BA%A3o%20s%E1%BB%91%20l%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng%20l%E1%BB%9Bn%20kh%C3%B4ng%20ph%E1%BA%A3i%20lo%20l%E1%BA%AFng%E3%80%91j5vvbyxdn
```

*(I have replaced the real domain name with `example.com`)*

Comment: If you visit those URLs is there content on them?  If so, it sounds as if your site was hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are either:

- Trying to get information from your database (hacking attempts)
- Trying to create content on your site (presumably link hacking)

Either way, a few recommendations:

- Search pages should never be crawled by robots (i.e., Google, Bing). You should mark those pages as **noindex**.
- Always sanitize the search variable as much as possible. For example, only allow characters, numbers, and spaces, but nothing more.
- Whenever possible, don't print out the search query (i.e., You searched for XXX)

These tips should mitigate any current and future attacks.

Comment: thanks so much for the support man! I might not be able to perform all of it but I think my developer could. Should I simply share the 3 points you have mentioned above? 
Or are there any instructions to give?

Comment: Your developer should be able to make the changes directly or Google on how to implement them if in doubt.